# Is it possible to sleep for a certain amount of cycles

Tags: c#, sleep, cpu-cycles

I was wondering if there was a possibility to let a thread sleep for a certain amount of CPU-cycles?

I thought about just inserting "nop"'s but I'm not sure if they get optimized away and I was hoping for a high-level solution.

Is there anything nice you could recommend me? If not can I prevent, that manually inserted "nop"'s get optimized away without disabling all optimizations?
Kind regards

Lukas Häfliger

EDIT: as another question: is it possible to measure the amount of cycles needed during execution for a certain code fragment?

Comment: Some high-level compilers allow to exclude some part of the program from optimization, or even set a certain optimization level on that part. Heck, even Delphi 5 allowed it, but I have not yet seen such a compiler directive in VisualStudio.

Comment: Have you looked at System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait?

Comment: As I am not completely bound to C# would a switch to something like c++/c add this functionality?

Comment: Windows is a multithreaded system, you will never know how many CPU-cycles that has parsed between start and finished.  C# is an interpreted language and partially optimized, You will never be able to tell how many CPU-cycles that your code will be using.  The question is really not relevant when talking c#.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I think that's the closest we can get. Thanks

Comment: Profiler is the answer to your second question... Goal of first part is unclear - if you really need waste precisely measured number of cycles - check CPU manuals, find instructions with most stable timing and use them in a loop (likely will need to target particular families of CPU).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov since I didn't want CPU dependency I was looking for a high-level approach but I think you way is the way to go. (That was my idea by inserting nop's since they should only use 1 cycle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no, because there isn't a 1:1 mapping between cycles and instructions (indeed, many instructions are executed per-cycle), and when you have things like instruction-pipelining, branch-prediction and speculative-execution it clearly becomes unpredictable.

Another reason is that there isn't an interrupt based on CPU cycles (or instructions), instead threads sleep based on a hardware timer interrupt or the operating system scheduler polling the current thread queue given the current time.

Finally, even if it were possible in hardware, the Windows API (which .NET uses internally) does not expose any other sleeping parameters besides a timespan in miliseconds (and a milisecond is potentially tens of thousands of CPU cycles anyway).

In C# the question is rather nonsensical because the code will be JIT-compiled based on the current platform, which means you can't predict the hardware instructions used for a given block of code, and even then there is the possibility that your CIL might be executed by an interpreter instead of JIT'd to reduce startup latency, and that throws the CPU instruction count waaaay off.